# bcc me when someone sends an email from my email address

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook

I want to create a rule (Outlook, Transport, or otherwise) that automatically adds my email address to the BCC field when an email is being sent using my email address.

**The specific case**: Assistants to an attorney send emails from the attorney's email address all the time. Now the attorney wants to know when the assistant is sending the email and review what they sent off.

Comment: I'm confused. What address would be BCC'd? A different/alternate address?

Comment: User@company.com is my email address. If my assistant has "send-as" permission on my mailbox, they're able to send an email that comes from User@company.com.  I want to be bcc'd every time someone does that so I want to add User@company.com into the bcc field

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if Exchange could do an auto-BCC rule back to the same sender (user@company.com).  It might be possible but that seems like it would be prone to looping/configuration issues.

That being said, Outlook does have a registry setting that lets you choose where sent items for delegate actions get stored.  It's described here:

- Outlook 2003 hotfix: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;959628
- Outlook 2007 hotfix: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;972148
- Outlook 2010: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2181579
- Outlook 2013: I wasn't able to find a KB on it but forum posts suggest that it's still there: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/dc5ad62c-7d26-4cdc-800c-ad97ebfa3846/delegatesentitemsstyle-group-policy-for-outlook-2013?forum=officesetupdeploy

Essentially it comes down to the following key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\<OfficeVersion>\Outlook\Preferences
DWORD: DelegateSentItemsStyle
Data Value: 1
```

If set to `1`, Outlook will save the sent items to the sent items folder of the mailbox that the user is sending on behalf of.  This would let you check your own sent items folder for any messages that were sent by you or were sent on your behalf.

Additional blog article about it is here: http://www.msexchange.org/blogs/walther/news/outlook-2010-delegate-access-and-the-infamous-sent-items-folder-behavior-650.html